# Use Nvidia as DMA devices is possible?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, dma, rdma

I've been trying lately to find a DMA like approach to PC memory, as I want to play around a bit with dma in windows os for fun. On the internet I came across, RDMA,DMA and Cuda from nvidia GPUs. I would like to just have an example of in visual studio on windows of how to achieve this.  Come on who read this help or give an example of how to read a specific memory address from pc ram with DMA from Nvidia gpu.

I would like to just have an example of in visual studio on windows of how to achieve this.  Come on who read this help or give an example of how to read a specific memory address from pc ram with DMA from Nvidia gpu.